# How To Change Stack Overflow Email

Tags: support, email, openid

Surprisingly I'm having difficulty determining how to change my email address for Stack Overflow and associated sites.  I've been using OpenID via Google and would like to log in with my work email address no longer using Google or FaceBook and not loose my questions, reputation, badges, etc.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: I think [this answer over on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-login-providers) might be just what you're looking for.